# Controlling Carat in as3 with setSelection

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, text

Ok I took some time and figured out to my surprise. 
and unfortunately I couldn't just use standard arrow keys. Im making a simulator of a label maker and it has to work to the letter, arrow keys, and everthing.

```
var boop = textSelect.text.length;
var snoop = boop;
bbbutton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, backBtns);

function backBtns(event:MouseEvent):void
{


    snoop -=  1;
    stage.focus = textSelect;

    textSelect.setSelection( snoop,snoop);
}
```

Comment: This code will always set it to the end of the text. Isn't the left and right arrow default behavior working for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can accomplish this by using a textField's `caretIndex` property.

Assuming `textSelect` is a `TextInput` component, if it's a `textField`, just remove the .textField property from the lines below.

```
//this gets the current caret position, and subtracts one (if not already at 0)
var pos:int = textSelect.textField.caretIndex > 0 ? textSelect.textField.caretIndex - 1 : 0;

//this sets the selection to adjusted caret postion
textSelect.setSelection(pos,pos);
```